# How to determine cookie validity?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am starting the session as

```
 session_start(); //So This session will get destroyed when user exit the browser
```

I set the cookie as

```
 setcookie('cookie',$value,time()+3*60);
 $_SESSION['cookie'] = true; //When user log in, I don't need to get the 
                               salt again from db and do all the security 
                               checks. Assume it as a cache
```

This suggesion is suggested in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88034/remember-me-functionality-for-a-website).

The problem is, cookie gets expired after 3 minutes. But session exists. So user tries to login after 3 minutes

```
    if($_SESSION['cookie'])
    {
      //success
    }
    else
     {
         //Authenticate user
     }
```

But this is wrong. Since cookie expired, else part should execute. But if part gets executed. I understand that session is still alive. How do I handle this situation?

I understand that it is due to that `time()+3*60`. But how do I implement that cache thing?

Comment: `$_SESSION['cookie']` has nothing to do with the cookie.

Comment: `time()*3*60` is not 3 mins.

Comment: To expire in 3 minutes it should be `time() + 3*60` -- add, not multiply.

Comment: Please see the edits. Thanks Barmer

Answer (score 0):

You need check cookie not in $_SESSION.
Check them in $_COOKIE.

As example:

```
if($_COOKIE['cookie'])
{
   //success
}
else
{
     //Authenticate user
}
```

Comment: $_SESSION lifetime is not related to cookie lifetime

Comment: Yea:) This will work I guess. Let me try. Thanks for understanding

Comment: @GopsAB Also, check isset($_COOKIE['cookie']) and check value, because is possible to write cookie in client(browser)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and session variables are not related (except that PHP internally uses a cookie named `PHPSESSID` to connect the client to its session). Expiring the cookie doesn't have any effect on a session variable with the same name. If you want to test whether the cookie has expired, use:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie']))
```